# Is there a way to paginate an API call to ec2 DescribeImages?

Tags: api, amazon-ec2, pagination

How do you paginate API calls in EC2?

I made a simple call to [`DescribeImages`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeImages.html) on EC2 (without any of the optional query parameters), and it takes about 20 seconds to respond, returning hundreds or thousands of items in XML.

Is there a way to say "give me the first 20", or define some `LIMIT`, `PAGE`, or `OFFSET`? Or is there no way to paginate?

**update**

It gives me back 17051 images.

Comment: http://www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/541 https://aws.amazon.com/amis/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to paginate the result of this particular API action, however, given you are currently using it *without any of the optional query parameters*, you might be missing out on a specific subtlety of [DescribeImages](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeSnapshots.html), namely that by default it also returns images you do not own - specifically *Amazon EC2 returns all AMIs for which you have launch permissions*, which also includes the huge amount of publicly available images for example:

> Images available to you include public images, private images that you
>   own, and private images owned by other AWS accounts but for which you
>   have explicit launch permissions.

Accordingly, many use cases strongly suggest to restrict this via the `Owner.n` request parameter and specify e.g. `self` to only include AMIs owned by you.

- Please note that this applies to the related [DescribeSnapshots](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ApiReference-query-DescribeSnapshots.html) as well.

Comment: Ok cool, that's helpful I'll definitely use that. Still though I'd like to be able to search _all_ images in the community, like what you get here: https://aws.amazon.com/amis/. Any way to do that?

Comment: Well, those are returned if you omit the `Owner.n` parameter, albeit unfortunately without pagination, which is why it takes ages, as you already experienced. If you are aiming for your own search interface, I'd suggest to either scan and cache (and potentially index) all images via a scheduled task, or use faceted browsing via the multitude of available filters (and cache those results in turn eventually, if the filtering doesn't yield significant performance gains already). Even AWS hasn't really solved this yet, the 'launch instance' wizard has become painfully slow over time for example.

Comment: Perfect, well thanks for letting me know there is a limitation :)